# Implement hierarchical data from Postgresql DB to Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database which has a hierarchical data. `GrandParents > Parents > Child`.

The database keeps data about all kinds of fabric.

Now I need to add this data to a Ruby on Rails app that I'm building. The app is about all kinds of fabric.

The plan is to have the user able to select his desired `Parent` or `Child` and see the values that the selected type of fabric has.  Some fabrics have `childs` so in that case the user is prompted with a selection of the `childs` of that parent.

My plan is to import the data from the Postgresql DB to the Rails app DB and then build Ruby/SQL queries to go through the database to find the selected fabric for the user.

So can anyone inform me on what is the best way to set this up in the app?

Should I use `f.select` and lots of `if` and `else` or is there another, better way?

**UPDATE**  **SCHEMA**

Since I've not yet set up the DB in Ruby on Rails, there is no Schema file from rails. This is what I got from PGadmin.

```
CREATE TABLE fabric_category (
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    category_name character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE fabric (
    category_id integer,
    category_name character varying(255),
    fabric_id integer NOT NULL,
    fabric_name character varying(255),
    type character varying(255),
    elasticy character varying(255),
    color character varying(255),
    density character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE sub_fabric (
    category_id integer,
    category_name character varying(255),
    fabric_id integer,
    fabric_name character varying(255),
    sub_fabric_id integer NOT NULL,
    sub_fabric_name character varying(255),
    type character varying(255),
    elasticy character varying(255),
    color character varying(255),
    density character varying(255)
);
```

So `fabric_category` is for example `Wool` 
in the `fabric` table are the various types of wool. for example. `goat_wool`, `sheep_wool`etc.

Then in the `sub_fabric` table is the sub types of wool, for example `fine_goat_wool`, `rough_goat_wool` and `recycled_goat_wool` for example.

So the user selects a fabric_category,  then the fabric, and in some cases the sub_fabric.

Comment: This is far too broad/vague/opinion based. What do you mean by `GrandParents > Parents > Child`? Are these different tables? A self-joined table? Is each fabric explicitly labeled as a `parent/child`, or can any object have an unlimited chain of ancestors?

Comment: I don't see how "`f.select`" is an answer to your question, and no I would not recommend that you use "lots of `if`/`else` statements". However, I cannot suggest a proper solution without first understanding your question.

Comment: I understand it's  broad/vague/opinion based.  The database is like :  1 Wool => (1,1) Sheep Wool ,(1,2) Goat Wool, (1,3) Llama Wool => (1,1,1) fine Sheep Wool, (1,1,2) rough Sheep Wool , (1,2,3) fine Goat Wool ,(1,2,3) rough Goat Wool.

Comment: So if the user  Selects Wool,  he is prompted with option of sheep wool, goat wool, Llama wool. then the user selects either of those than the user can finally select if he wants fine or rough wool of desired type.

Comment: In order to avoid your question being flagged or downvotes I strongly recommend you update it and add the schema you have and elaborate on what exactly is the expected behavior.

Comment: I'll do it, thanks

Comment: Emphasis on the words: **database schema**. `(1,1,2) rough Sheep Wool` is not a schema.

Comment: Take a look at ancestry gem: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry
It could be a starting point.

Comment: Might be easiest to create a new db using the model generator, then copy your data over. You already have your data in a relational format (e.g. the `sub_fabric_id` foreign key) so you should be able to keep the same db structure - what the generators will do is build the glue that connects it to rails.

Answer (score 0):

A "direct conversion" of your current schema into rails (with some minor tweaks to follow rails conventions) could be something like:

#### Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE fabric_categories (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE fabrics (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    fabric_category_id integer,
    name character varying(255),
    fabric_type character varying(255),
    elasticity character varying(255),
    color character varying(255),
    density character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE sub_fabric (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    fabric_id integer,
    name character varying(255),
    fabric_type character varying(255),
    elasticity character varying(255),
    color character varying(255),
    density character varying(255)
);
```

I made a few *opinion-based** changes to your schema, so do not take this as gospel. Some fields have been renamed/removed. (Also note: I think you meant *elasticity*, not "elasticy".)

You could then set up three models as follows:

```
class FabricCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fabrics
end

class Fabric
  belongs_to :fabric_category
  has_many :sub_fabrics
end

class SubFabric
  belongs_to :fabric
end
```

This simple design may be sufficient for your needs. However, there are two clear issues with it:

1. What, really, is the difference between a `Fabric` and a `SubFabric`? Why are they being stored in two different tables?
2. Why can't you have a Sub-Sub-Fabric? Or a Sub-Sub-Sub-Fabric? It's clearly not practical to create *another* new table for each additional layer!

You *could* choose to solve (1) by using Single Table Inheritance. If you add a `type` column to the `fabrics` table, then both "parent" and "child" records will be stored in the same structure, in one table.

The solution to (2), however, was hinted in the comments above. You'd need to  implement a generic **tree** structure to build relationships. You could implement this yourself, or use a third-party library such as [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry):

```
class FabricCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fabrics
end

class Fabric
  belongs_to :fabric_category
  has_ancestry # <--- !!!
end
```